# Alert box Tip Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, alert, calculator

Hello I'm trying to get a tip calculator to appear all in alert boxes I'm struggling to get the code to work and to get the alert boxes and show up and to get the right calculations. I want it to show first in an alert box the total cost of bill and then to rate service and based on that ex. poor - 8% fair- 10$ good - 15% and excellent 20%. if anyone could help me with this thanks. link: http://jsfiddle.net/saber2356/wxy9zfn8/

javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>tip</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function calculateTip()
    {
        var bill, tip, answer;

        bill = document.TipCalculator.bill.value - 0;
        tip = document.TipCalculator.tip.value - 0;



        var cal= tip;
        if ("poor") { Math.round(((8/100) * bill)*100)/100;
        }else if ("fair"){ Math.round(((10/100) * bill)*100)/100;
        }else if ("good"){ Math.round(((15/100) * bill)*100)/100;
        }else ("excellent");{ Math.round(((20/100) * bill))*100/100;
        }




        bill = Math.round((bill + tip)*100)/100;




        document.TipCalculator.answer.value = bill;
        document.TipCalculator.Total.value = Total;

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>

    <script>function myFunction(){
    var calculateTip = prompt("Amount of Bill: ");}
    if (!number)){ alert ("Sorry cost " " must be a number"); }

    }else {("Rate your service as either: Poor, Fair, Good or Excellent ");}

    }else if {("Final Total = ")}

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, please let me know if I misunderstood.

There are much better ways to do what you want than to use alert boxes and prompts but if you must use them try this:

```js
function calculateTip (bill) {
    var rating, tip, answer;

    if (isNaN(bill)) {
        alert("Sorry cost must be a number"); 
        return;
    }      

    rating = prompt("Rate your service as either: Poor, Fair, Good or Excellent", "");
                
    if (rating === "poor") { 
        tip = Math.round(((8/100) * bill)*100)/100;
        
    } else if (rating === "fair") { 
        tip = Math.round(((10/100) * bill)*100)/100;
        
    } else if (rating === "good") { 
        tip = Math.round(((15/100) * bill)*100)/100;
        
    } else if (rating === "excellent") { 
        tip = Math.round(((20/100) * bill))*100/100;
      
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, you rated wrong");
      return;
    }

    bill = Math.round((bill + tip)*100)/100;

    alert("Your tip is: " + tip);
    alert("Your total is: " + bill);
}

calculateTip(prompt("Amount of Bill: ", 0));
```

```html
<h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
```

A much better way than this would be to use form elemnts. Let me know if you would like to see this answer instead.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for just one more question

Comment: how would I generate the results to print out a table ex: 4 columns that have bill rating tip totalbill and underneath those would have what I entered in the alert boxes with the calculations thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Calummm's answer is correct and can't really be improved upon, but it mentioned some better ways to do it, so I'll make some suggestions here.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxy9zfn8/13/)

One is to separate out the "settings" from the rest of your code. Often, your HTML is good for that. Here is a dropdown with the percentages as values:

```
<select id="service" onchange="valueChange()">
  <option id="poor" value="8">Poor</option>
  <option id="fair" value="10">Fair</option>
  <option id="good" value="15">Good</option>
  <option id="excellent" value="25">Excellent</option>
</select>
```

If we play our cards right, we'll be able to add or remove options here, like maybe an "outstanding" with 30% or a "horrific" with 1%, and then change nothing else in our code. The JavaScript will just pick those changes up and go with them.

We'll treat "bill" as an input too...just a number box in this case.

```
<input type="number" id="bill" onchange="valueChange()" onkeyup="valueChange()"/>
```

Then we'll make some places to spit out the results:

```
<h2>Tip</h2>
<h3 id="tip">0.00</h3>

<h2>Total</h2>
<h3 id="total">0.00</h3>
```

Now we need a simple math function that just takes two numbers and spits out the tip, nothing more.

```
function calculateTip(percent, bill){
  return parseFloat((percent * bill / 100), 2);
}
```

Now we need to marry the input / output with the function. That's done by this function, which is called by the event handlers in the HTML above.

```
function valueChange(){

  //input
  var percent = parseInt(document.getElementById("service").value);
  var bill = parseInt(document.getElementById("bill").value);

  //the raw math
  var tip = calculateTip(percent, bill);
  var total = tip + bill;

  //output
  document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = tip;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```